# why is the .ajaxError is executed twice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a jQuery function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ajaxError(function() {
        // Show only an alert();
        alert("An error occurred. Please try again after some time.");
    })

</script>
```

The button that is triggering the call:

```
 <p:commandButton id="deleteButton"
     value="Delete Urls"
     styleClass="action-button"
     actionListener="#{controller.deleteUploadedUrls}"
     immediate="true"
     update="btnPanel messages"
     oncomplete="view.disableNextTabs();"/>
```

The problem is that the alert is displayed twice.

Why is the alert displayed twice?

Comment: Submitting two AJAX requests?  Impossible to say given your _extremely vague_ code sample.

Comment: Are you making multiple ajax calls within your page?

Comment: It is displayed twice because either two ajax requests or failing, or you are binding to the event twice.

Comment: The error is occurring on the selecting the command button. I will update the question with the commandButton.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which ajax requests are been made ? I am new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you use an `update panel`, which is part of the `ASP.NET WebForm Framework`:

```
update="btnPanel messages"
oncomplete="view.disableNextTabs();"
```

The `update panel` goes through the whole page livecycle. When your page has been loaded, your `errorHandler` executes the first time; it executes once again after an update.

Comment: I removed the 'update="btnPanel messages"' completely and it is still displaying the alert twice :( This is in primefaces.

Comment: It is an ajaxError handler, so your ajax request fails. Open your dev tool and check out.

Comment: I am making it fail by throwing an exception server side and not catching it. I am implementing exception handling for errors occurring on ajax calls. Is there another way on the client side that can display some message when an error occurs ?